# How do I decompress multiple json gzip files in a column?

Tags: python, json, gzip

I have an csv file of thousands of json.gz files in a column. My goal is to iterate through all rows in the column to decompress each json.gz file.

| index | location |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | '0_location_data.json.gz' |
| 1 | '1_location_data.json.gz' |

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools, gzip


jsonfilename = list(df['location])

it = (gzip.open(f, 'rt') for f in jsonfilename)

for line in itertools.chain.from_iterable(it):
     print(line)
```

My error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '0_location_data.json.gz'
```

My goal is to decompress all of these files so I can then normalize them into a csv.

Answer (score 0):

```
it = (gzip.open(f, 'rb') for f in jsonfilename)
```

This may be the right argument given gzip produces a binary file.